# Prove the direct sum: $V = im(T)⊕im(S)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, computer-science

Let there be V vector space.
we are given two linear transformations - $S,T : V \to V$ such that:

1. $T + S = Iv$
2. $T \circ S = 0 $
3. $T \circ T  = 0 $

Using all of the above - I need to prove that:

---

$V = im(T)⊕im(S)$

---

I have tried to use the Rank–nullity theorem with no success, any help?

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $im(T)+im(S)\subseteq V$. To show that $V \subseteq im(T)+im(S)$, pick $v \in V$. Now, by (1), $T(v)+S(v)=I(v)=v$. So, $v \in im(T)+im(S)$ and hence $V \subseteq im(T)+im(S)$.

To show that the sum is direct, pick $v \in im(T) \cap im(S)$. Then, by definition, there exists $a \in V$ such that $T(a)=v$. Now, by (1), $T(a)+S(a)=I(a)=a$ and so, by (2) and (3), $0=0+0=T(T(a))+T(S(a))=T(T(a)+S(a))=T(a)=v$, thus, $v=0$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much! one more question if I may: if $T \circ T  = T $ will it make any big difference in the method shown?

Comment: @OmriBraha You would need to change it a little, in that case T would be identity on its range so S would kill any element from the intersection. If $S(b)=v$, then $S(S(b))=0$ so you would do the same except $a$ is swapped with $b$ and $S$ is applied to the sum instead of $T$ this time.

Comment: But how we can assume that $S(S(b)) = 0$ ?

Comment: @OmriBraha I did not assume that, observe that $v=T(v)+S(v)=v+S(v)$, so, $S(v)=0$, where $S(b)=v$.